# Oracle Database - Character Set

Tags: plsql, character-encoding, character, oracle12c, database-administration

How can I keep the special characters in my package, when I compile using sqlplus or any other tool?

> NLS_CHARACTERSET : WE8MSWIN1252
>   The client character´s set:  unknown
>   The problem is: Data Presentation
>   OS and DB :  UNIX \ Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
>
> Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
>   PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
>   CORE 12.1.0.2.0 Production
>   TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
>   NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg1
AS
  procedure sp 
  IS
  v_var VARCHAR2(100);
  BEGIN
        v_var := '**último**';
  END;

   END;
```

When I do describe the package look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY HR.pkg1
AS
  procedure sp
  IS
  v_var VARCHAR2(100);
  BEGIN
        v_var := '**£ltimo**';     
  END;


   END;
```

Comment: So is the problem really that “The client character´s set: unknown”? Do you not know the NLS_LANG setting, or the operating system character set, or both? Is the string correct in the data dictionary (dumping it would tell you) and only displayed incorrectly - you seem to suggest that but how have you established it?

Answer (score 0):

There is generic way to enter arbitrary unicode data into oracle databases limiting oneself to the ascii charset:

1. Determine the utf-8 representation of the target text as a sequence of bytes in hex.

   Use an utf8-savvy editor and enter the text you wish to transfer to the db. Many editors come with a hex mode that allows you to inspect the utf8 representationand write it down someplace else. Alternatively use a dedicated hex editor or use cli tools like `od` (linux) to produce file content as a tabulated sequence of octets represented in hex:

   ```
    od --output-duplicates --format x1 --width=16 demo.txt
   ```

   The output needs some postprocessing to get rid of the line numbers and blanks, however, that should be straightforward. For bulk data use `sed` or a similar tool.
2. Convert the hex string to oracle's `raw` datatype.

   Calling `HEXTORAW(x)` in PlSql does the trick.
3. Convert the `raw` data to `varchar2`, ie. the databases character set.

   Use the plsql package procedure `utl_i18n.raw_to_char`. Its second argument specifies the source encoding.

In summary, the method boils down to a query similar to (test string are the lowercase letters `a` through `f` followed by the german umlauts ) :

```
 select utl_i18n.raw_to_char ( hextoraw ( '616263646566c3a4c3b6c3bcc384c396c39cc39f' ), 'AL32UTF8' ) from dual;
```

In your package you would write:

```
 v_var := '**' || utl_i18n.raw_to_char ( hextoraw ( 'c3ba' ), 'AL32UTF8' )
               || 'ltimo**';
   -- c3ba being the utf8 encoding of unicode codepoint U+00fa,
   -- 'LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH ACUTE'
```

Obviously the technique only works if the database character set is capable of representing the characters in the first place.

**Shortcuts**

1. You may use any other source encoding the special characters you need are representable in as long as the db is aware of that encoding. Namely the iso 8859-x series of encodings for latin alphabets may be used. In your case for `ú` and iso8859-1:

   ```
    v_var := utl_i18n.raw_to_char ( hextoraw ( 'fa' ), 'WE8ISO8859P1' ) from dual;
   ```
2. Using the National Character Set in your db, you may enter unicode characters by their code points in your literal strings. Just wrap the literal strings with the `UNISTR` function:

   ```
   v_var := TO_CHAR(UNISTR('**\00faltimo**')) from dual;
   ```